# Find duplicated values in a column and extract the data in the same row to the first occurence

Tags: excel

I have a project like the image 1 :

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aidp7.jpg)

And I want to keep only the first occurrence on column A and fill each row with the other occurrences, so the result will be like this image 2:

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyr8v.jpg)

Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a formula In your first output cell:

```
=IF(COLUMN(A:A)<=COUNTIF($A:$A,$C1),INDEX($B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("ZZZ",$B:$B)))/($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,MATCH("ZZZ",$B:$B))=$C1),COLUMN(A:A))),"")
```

copy over and down till you get blanks.

[image]

Comment: Wow. Exactly what I needed. Thank you Scott!

Comment: @user2409512 please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer